# Cordova Facebook Login - Sudden Failure on Oct 1st 2020

Tags: facebook, cordova, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-authentication

We are using cordova-plugin-facebook4 to manage Facebook login within our Cordova apps.

Facebook login suddenly started failing today (Oct 1st 2020).

When calling the facebookConnectPlugin.login, it keeps returning this error:

> "Facebook error: Caught exception: (#200) Missing Permissions"

It has been working fine all the while, and our app is authorized for those permissions. This is the code used:

```
facebookConnectPlugin.login(["email","public_profile","user_birthday","user_location"], 
    function(response) {
        // do something
    },
    function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
);
```

We tried completely removing all the permissions, or just using a single one like "email", but the same error persists. The error happens on both iOS and Android.

We are using Cordova 9.0, cordova-plugin-facebook4 6.4.0.

Please advise as users are not able to login to our apps since today. Thank you.

**UPDATE:**
There appears to be a global Facebook Login outage affecting many websites and apps: https://twitter.com/search?q=facebook%20login%20&src=typed_query&f=live

Also, if you are using "link" permission on website FB authentication, you can try removing it as that is additionally a cause for permission error too.

We are monitoring it to see if this problem is resolved, and will close the question if so.

Comment: Thank you for your replies... it appears that there's a global Facebook Login outage that affects lots of websites and apps, with the same permission error:  https://twitter.com/search?q=facebook%20login%20&src=typed_query&f=live

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be a global Facebook Login outage affecting many websites and apps: https://twitter.com/search?q=facebook%20login%20&src=typed_query&f=live

For website FB Graph API integration, if you are querying the "link" field for User, you can try removing it as that seems to additionally cause permission error too.

The login problem seems to have subsided after half a day. There are still occasional login errors but after a few retries it will go through. It is definitely an issue at Facebook's end, so the only thing we can do is to wait it out.